# What skill did I just learn?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I've been way to focused on not dying, I forgot to check what skills I had just unlocked when I leveled up. I had gotten out of my game a short while later and when I returned I realized I didn't check what I unlocked :( Is there a way to see recent unlocks for your character? Instead of going back through each skill guessing what the unlock might have been.

Comment: No there is not

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to the [Diablo 3 Game Guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/).  Each class has a "Progression" tab, that will show you exactly what skills, runes, and passives you unlock at each level.

There is no way in-game to see what you recently unlocked.

Comment: +1 , these charts are a really nice presentation of your skill progression. [Here's a link to the monk one for an example](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/progression).

Answer (score 8):

In the skills tab, there should be a "NEW" tag above each new skill (or skill with a new rune), and above the passives if you've gotten a new passive. If you open a specific skill page or the passives page, the tag should appear above the particular runes/passives that were unlocked. These will only go away if you mouse over the new skill/rune/passive.

Comment: That works when you unlock it and check right away, my problem was that I left the game before checking them. When I went back in the "NEW" tag didn't show.